# Documentation for the XML format for files referenced from the kotlinc -Xbuild-file argument

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

Where is the documentation for the XML format for the contents of files referenced from the kotlinc `-Xbuild-file` argument?

The XML looks something like:

```
<modules>
    <module name="module-name" type="java-production" outputDir="/Users/user/code/project/build/classes/kotlin/main">
        <sources path="/Users/user/code/project/src/main/kotlin/package/Class.kt"/>
        <javaSourceRoots path="/Users/user/code/project/src/main/java"/>
        <classpath path="/Users/user/code/project/libs/lib.jar"/>
    </module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per JetBrains, there is not documentation for this XML format since it is not a public API.

But the parser source for that format is in GitHub:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/cli/cli-common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/modules/ModuleXmlParser.java